# How do you use freeze_graph.py in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am having trouble freezing a model in Tensorflow. I want to use it in Unity but they require a frozen graph as a .bytes file not .pb. Is there another way to get the bytes file other than freeze_graph.py? I keep getting this error:

TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases:0", shape=(12,), dtype=float32)

This is what I am using currently :

```
freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/frozen_inference_graph.pb',
input_binary = True,
input_checkpoint = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt',
output_node_names = "num_detections,detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes",
output_graph = 'BytesModel/bytesModel.bytes',
clear_devices = True, initializer_nodes = "",input_saver = "",
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all", filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0")
```

Comment: Please provide complete stack trace