# Tensorflow: Load a .pb file and then save it as a frozen graph issues

Tags: python, tensorflow

This question is very similar to this one: [How do you use freeze_graph.py in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837854/how-do-you-use-freeze-graph-py-in-tensorflow)
but that one has not been answered and I have a different approach to the problem. Thus I would like some input.

I am also trying to load a .pb binary file and then freeze it. This is the code I tried.

Let me know if this gives you any ideas. This does not return errors. It just crashes my jupyter notebook.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saved_model_pb2
from tensorflow.python.util import compat

with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename ='saved_model.pb' # binary .pb file
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:

        data = compat.as_bytes(f.read()) # reads binary
        sm = saved_model_pb2.SavedModel() 
        print(sm)
        sm.ParseFromString(data) # parses through the file
        print(sm)
        if 1 != len(sm.meta_graphs):
            print('More than one graph found. Not sure which to write')
            sys.exit(1)

        g_in = tf.import_graph_def(sm.meta_graphs[0].graph_def)
        output_graph = "frozen_graph.pb"

        # Getting all output nodes for the frozen graph
        output_nodes = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
        # This not working fully   
        output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
            output_nodes# The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
        ) 

        # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))
        print(g_in)
LOGDIR='.'
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR)
train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

This code should generate a frozen file, but I don't completely understand tensorflow's saving mechanisms. If I take out the freezing the graph part from this code I get and events.out. file that can be read by tensorboard.

Answer (score 4):

So after a lot of stumbling I realize that I was just loading the meta graph. Not the whole graph with variables. Here is code that does so:

```
def frozen_graph_maker(export_dir,output_graph):
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], export_dir)
    output_nodes = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
    output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            sess.graph_def,
            output_nodes# The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
    )       
    # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
    with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
def main():
    export_dir='/dir/of/pb/and/variables'
    output_graph = "frozen_graph.pb"
    frozen_graph_maker(export_dir,output_graph)
```

I realized that I was just loading the meta graph. I would love if someone could confirm my understanding of what was failing. With compat.as_bytes I was just loading it as a meta graph. Is there a way of integrating variables after doing that kind of loading or should I stick with `tf.saved_model.loader.load()` ? 
My attempt of loading was completely wrong as it wasn't even calling the folder of variables.

Another question:  with `[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]` I am putting all nodes into the output_nodes, should I just put the last node? It works with just the last node. What is the difference?

Comment: There are no words I can use to express how much I appreciate this answer!

Comment: `tf.saved_model.loader.load()` is the default way of loading saved_model. So you have to stick to it. For your second question,  `output_nodes` should only contain the nodes you want to export, here in your case last node. So, you can freely only add last node.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would have been as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

pb_saved_model = "/Users/vedanshu/saved_model/"

_graph = tf.Graph()
with _graph.as_default():
    _sess = tf.Session(graph=_graph)
    model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(_sess, ["serve"], pb_saved_model)

with tf.gfile.GFile("/Users/vedanshu/frozen_graph/frozen.pb", "wb") as f:
    f.write(model.SerializeToString())
```

If your saved_model has variables in it, it can be converted to constant as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

pb_saved_model = "/Users/vedanshu/saved_model/"
OUTPUT_NAMES = ["fc2/Relu"]

_graph = tf.Graph()
with _graph.as_default():
    _sess = tf.Session(graph=_graph)
    model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(_sess, ["serve"], pb_saved_model)
    graphdef = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
    frozen_graph = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(_sess,graphdef, OUTPUT_NAMES)
    frozen_graph = tf.graph_util.remove_training_nodes(frozen_graph)

with tf.gfile.GFile("/Users/vedanshu/frozen_graph/frozen.pb", "wb") as f:
    f.write(frozen_graph)
```